# Exact Target SQL- LIKE condition does not return anything

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, automation, sql

New to ET and have written a query in the automation studio. I have two tables I am looking through and am trying to return what matches my LIKE condition. The LIKE is looking for emails from TableA that have a name from TableB in it. It does not seem to return anything at the moment and I was wondering if anyone could see what I am doing wrong.

**Additional Info:** I was asked to find gender based on Name in TableA but most of the records lack a Name. Since some emails have a person's name in it I am trying to check email as well. TableB has a Name column and a Gender column.

```
SELECT TableA.Name, TableA.Email, TableB.Gender
FROM TableA INNER JOIN TableB
ON TableA.Name = TableB.Name OR TableB.Name LIKE '%' + TableA.Email + '%'
```

Comment: Why would you try to match for rows in TableB where the Name is like an email address?

Comment: What columns are in TableB?

Comment: Please do not create multiple user accounts. It is an abuse of the system and may get you banned. If you need to merge accounts, please go through the [contact us](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/contact) link to reach out to the Community Management team.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got to a solution that works for me. Open to suggestions of course but this gets me the results I needed. Again, working in Exact Target.

```
    SELECT TableA.Name, TableA.Email,TableB.Gender 
    FROM TableA INNER JOIN TableB 
    ON TableA.Name = TableB.Name OR  TableB.Name LIKE 
    SUBSTRING(TableA.Email,0, CHARINDEX('@', TableA.Email,0))
```